# How to delete and refresh page using AsyncNotifier in Flutter Riverpod 2

Tags: flutter, state-management, riverpod

I have two AsyncNotifier (and providers offcourse) in my project. One is a AsyncNotifier<List> to get the list of todos say from a REST API. And a AsyncNotifier to delete todo by id.

I listen the delete todo notifer on the same page/widget where the todo list notifier is used to show a success/failure sanckbar after the delete button is pressed.

On the build method:

```
ref.listen<AsyncValue<void>>(
      deleteTodoControllerProvider,
      (_, state) => state.whenOrNull(
        error: (error, stackTrace) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(error.toString()),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );

    final todoList = ref.watch(todoListControllerProvider);
```

The delete button onPressed:

```
 ref.read(deleteTodoControllerProvider.notifier)
                                   .deleteTodoById(todo.id!);
```

My problem is I want to refresh the page after deleting the todo without calling the API again. I mean want to update the todo list state locally like using `removeWhere`.

I tried calling `todoListProvider.invalidate()` on the todoDeleteProvider's listener but it calls the API again.

The other thing I was thinking is to create a method on the todo list notifier and call it on the listener.

Is it okay to mutate the state like that?

Answer (score 1):

> I mean want to update the todo list state locally like using `removeWhere`. [...] Is it okay to mutate the state like that?

Short answer: No.

As stated in the Riverpod 2 docs: the state is immutable. So in your case: you need to make a fresh copy of the list to get an update to the `ref.watch` that is in your build method.

According to the docs this would be the way to delete an item in a list:

```
  void removeTodo(String todoId) {
    // Again, our state is immutable. So we're making a new list instead of
    // changing the existing list.
    state = [
      for (final todo in state)
        if (todo.id != todoId) todo,
    ];
  }`
```

Source: [Riverpod 2 docs for NotifierProvider](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/providers/notifier_provider)

As long as you don't invalidate the `todoListProvider`, it should not be calling the API again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ref.watch(asyncNotifierListProvider)` to track changes. As soon as your list is updated (items added or removed), your widget will be rebuilt. Keep in mind that the sheet models must be immutable to work properly.